# Angular http post not working 1st time, but works on 2nd time

Tags: json, angular, http, typescript, post

Trying my first angular exercise. Receiving undefined value on 1st time from http post, but 2nd time getting proper response (Edge, Firefox). Thanks!

LoginService (Calls Http post method and returns observable)

```
login(loginRequest: LoginRequest){
console.log("LoginService.login - userName " + loginRequest.username);

let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
return this.http.post(this.http_url, loginRequest, options).map( res =>        
res.json());
```

LoginFormComponent (calls service class and convert JSON to typescript object)

```
  onSubmit() {
     this.loginSvc.login(this.loginRequest).subscribe(
       data => this.loginResponseStr = data,
       error => alert(error),
       () => console.log('Request completed')
     );

    var loginResponse = new LoginResponse();
    loginResponse.fillFromJSON(JSON.stringify(this.loginResponseStr));
    console.log(loginResponse.status);
    console.log(loginResponse.statusDesc);

    if(loginResponse.status == "SUCCESS"){
      this.router.navigate(['/home-page']);
}
```

Console log

```
LoginService.login - userName admin  main.bundle.js:370:9
undefined  main.bundle.js:266:9
undefined  main.bundle.js:267:9
Request completed  main.bundle.js:263:181
LoginService.login - userName admin  main.bundle.js:370:9
SUCCESS  main.bundle.js:266:9
VALID USER  main.bundle.js:267:9
Request completed  main.bundle.js:263:181
```

Comment: Http calls are asynchronous. You need to move your code that checks the response into the onNext handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular server calls are asynchronous, that mean the code wont wait for the server to respond before executing the rest of the code. Such as PHP. So you would not see a blank page waiting for the server to send data. When you want to deal with the respose come from a server call you have to add all the code within the `subscribe`; that means if this information needed to be passed to another service.
Your code should look like this.

```js
onSubmit() {
  this.loginSvc.login(this.loginRequest).subscribe(
    data => {
      this.loginResponseStr = data
      var loginResponse = new LoginResponse();
      loginResponse.fillFromJSON(JSON.stringify(data));
      console.log(loginResponse.status);
      console.log(loginResponse.statusDesc);

      if (loginResponse.status == "SUCCESS") {
        this.router.navigate(['/home-page']);
      }
    },
    error => alert(error),
    () => console.log('Request completed')
  );
}
```